# Server doesn't take url parameters

Tags: php

After a test payment the bank sent me this url with some parameters:
The methid use by the bank is POST

```
https://www.example.net:443/demo/index.php?order&mybanque&success&ho?TPE=XXXX14&date=17%2f08%2f2018%5fa%5f14%3a31%3a35&montant=26%2e50EUR&reference=000000000055&MAC=5DA667XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX24C&texte-libre=gpdiv2vXXXXXXXXXXdd9iq&code-retour=payetest&cvx=oui&vld=1219&brand=VI&status3ds=-1&numauto=000000&originecb=FRA&bincb=000001&hpancb=A4F7BXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX9C87CBBEA&ipclient=XXX%2e158%2e61%2eXXX&originetr=CAN&veres=&pares=&modepaiement=CB
```

I have function like this

```
public static function getMethod() {

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'GET') return $_GET;
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST') return $_POST;

  die ('Invalid REQUEST_METHOD (not GET, not POST).');
}
```

On GET : I have this:

```
" array(4) { ["order"]=> string(0) "" ["desjardins"]=> string(0) "" ["success"]=> string(0) "" ["ho"]=> string(0) "" } string(77) "
```

On POST I have nothing

How to take the url parameter : `TPE=XXXX14&date=17%2f08%2f2018%5fa%5f14%3a31%3a35&montant=26%2e50EUR&reference=000000000055&MAC=5DA667XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX24C&texte-libre=gpdiv2vXXXXXXXXXXdd9iq`

Comment: how are you testing the POST request?

Comment: by a var_dump()

Comment: You have a `?` inside you url query it should be `&`. Here : `&ho?TPE=XXXX14&`

Answer (score 1):

The bank is sending you an invalid query string, using `&` as the separator before `TPE` instead of `&`. PHP isn't able to parse those parameters into `$_GET`.

You can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the original query string, and parse this yourself.

```
if (preg_match('/(<=?).*/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $match) {
    parse_str($match[0], $extra_params);
    $tpe = $extra_params['TPE'];
    $data = $extra_params['date'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Bamar, My problem is when he bank sent the POST request, I don"t arrive to take the URL parameters sent by the bank. TPE=XXXX14&date= ...  That's my problem,

Comment: They have two `?` in the URL. That's not valid. The first `?` separates the pathname from the parameters, PHP is ignoring everything after the second `?`

Comment: They should have `&` before `TPE=`, not `?`.

Comment: Yes Bamar, I know that, that's why I replace ? by &  and I rebuild the url.

Comment: Where are you doing that?

Comment: On the route function but I tested $_POST when the file start (first line on the code) and I have nothing. But if I put the url in my browser all is ok, I have the element.

Comment: They're sending it in URL parameters, not POST data, why are you testing `$_POST`?

Comment: Sincerely, I don't see nothing in this moment, I must a break I think ! how to have this information $_REQUEST don't give me the information.

Comment: My answer was just related to your code that tries to get either `$_GET` or `$_POST`. Your actual problem is different from that, the extra parameters aren't being put into either variable.

Comment: You need to talk to your bank about why they're sending you an incorrect URL in the first place, they need to fix that problem.

Comment: I do that, but it does'nt want to make that.

Comment: You can use `$_SERVER[''QUERY_STRING"]` to get the raw query string and parse it yourself.

Comment: `parse_str()` is supposed to give it a value.

Comment: Ok, I tested $_SERVER[''QUERY_STRING"] but I have not the url parameters. I think in mode test it does'nt sent the data parameters. It's weird, I must have a converstion with the support.  Thank you.